# C++ mktime changes value of my tm_struct

Tags: c++, c, mktime

I read bMonth from user;

```
time_t timestamp = time(NULL);
tm* birthday = localtime(&timestamp);

birthday->tm_mon = bMonth-1;

// now the tm_mon is set corectly

time_t birthStamp = mktime(birthday);

// now the tm_mon is 0
```

Why mktime changes the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mktime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/mktime/)

> A call to this function automatically adjusts the values of the
>   members of timeptr if they are off-range or -in the case of tm_wday
>   and tm_yday- if they have values that do not match the date described
>   by the other members.

Comment: "...do not match the date described by the other members." Thanks, I'm idiot.